# What does a low thrust apoapsis raising look like?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-thrust

Say you are in a simple circular orbit, $r = 1$ and want to raise your apoapsis to some higher altitude, say an orbit $r_P = 1, r_A = 2$

A high thrust spacecraft would to this in one impulse, at $\Delta v = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} - 1 \approx 0.15$.

But how would a low thrust spacecraft quickly achieve this?

One could of course "emulate" an impulse by only using the engine a short while for each revolution at periapsis. But this does not sound very time-efficient, as the engine isn't in use most of the time. To illustrate this, a circular-circular transfer from $r=1$ to $r=2$ can be achieved by a spiralling low-thrust craft much faster than by "emulating" a Hohmann transfer.

Is there some similar strategy to "spiralling" when the target orbit is not circular?

Comment: Surely the best "Low Thrust" apoapsis raising is to only use thrust at periapsis. Yes, it's time-consuming, but that is the trade-off.

Comment: @RoryAlsop "time-efficiency" is the metric here.

Comment: Okay - I think the two are pretty diametrically opposed. But I'm interested to see how much less fuel-efficient a spiral-type transfer would be. ie what is the actual trade-off.

Comment: None of these are duplicates but they address differences between impulsive and low-thrust maneuvers:  [Ratio of low-thrust slow spiral to Hohmann transfer ΔV?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34114) ahttps://space.stackexchange.com/q/28361nd [Spiraling out from circular orbit to escape via low thrust, what is γ (gamma)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28361) and [Hohmann transfer orbit Burn Duration](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46118) and [Why would a slow spiral from a C3 of zero take about 2.4 times as much ΔV as an impulsive maneuver?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28359)

Comment: Your example shows raising apoapsis without raising periapsis. Is that the intent, not to affect periapsis? If so, spiraling is precluded, and if it is truly low-thrust and the apoapsis raise is large (e.g., not a <1% increase), then multiple quasi-impulses at multiple periapsis passes would be required. The longer the thrust durations through periapsis, the more periapsis altitude will be affected, and might even require small *retro* apoapsis maneuvers to keep periapsis from creeping upward.

Comment: By the way, that upward creep in periapsis slows the periapsis velocity, so the power transferred by a constant-force engine is reduced and the total energy gain from a fixed-duration maneuver is also reduced. A periapsis-reduction maneuver at apoapsis, despite being retro, can wind up *reducing* the time needed to reach the target apoapsis!

Comment: @TomSpilker Increasing apoapsis only without affecting periapsis is indeed the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Different methods of low thrust optimization are discussed in Chapter 2 of "Low Thrust Trajectory Optimization in Cislunar and Translunar space", [a dissertation published in 2018 by Dr. Parrish](https://scholar.colorado.edu/concern/graduate_thesis_or_dissertations/ft848q86s).

In short, there is no analytical solution. There are several methods for low thrust optimization depending on the problem you'd like to solve. For orbits with lots of revolutions, it's usually recommended to do a Sims-Flanagan spiral method. Otherwise, a multiple shooting method is recommended, either direct or indirect (e.g. using costates).

Comment: "What does a low thrust apoapsis raising look like?" and "But how would a low thrust spacecraft efficiently achieve this?" ask for an example. So far this only provides information that someone intending to answer the question might find helpful. Are there any examples there that you can at least briefly summarize?

Comment: Are there good heuristic for the initial conditions of the costates, namely I played around with it and the reduced optimization problem does not look convex, so depending on the initial conditions one might not find the global optimum.

Comment: One method is to use a direct optimization (without costates) to seed the indirect optimization (with the costates). A direct optimization converges well even on random initial conditions. @uhoh, you're right, I should add some examples, but I'm currently developing some code for that, so I don't have anything to show yet :-(

Comment: @ChrisR I think of life as a process; the fun is in getting there, not being there.